# Adjust spaces between text or words in html

Tags: html, css, word-spacing

I have a problem is how adjust spaces between text or words in html. I want my result 2 "colon" alignment can adjust same line.

Below is my sample code:

```html
<tr><td style="font-size:11px;">Name :</td></tr><br>
<tr><td style="font-size:11px;">Date &nbsp;<span style="word-spacing:80px;">:</span></td></tr>
```

Now my result alignment cannot be same like:

[image: result]

I want the expected result is same like below:

[image: result_2]

I have try to use `<p>` to replace `<span>` adjust the alignment, but the "Colon" will break down. Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: This will only work if you have a monospaced font. Or, since you're already using tables, why not just put the colons into their own column to the right of the rest of the text?

Comment: Because will effect something where. So I try to see got other method to space the colon

Comment: There are key words missing in your comment and I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and the only "hacky" way I found is this:
"Put your text and separator (`:` in this case) in a wrapper (like `<div>`) and align them.

```css
.cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50px; /* just to see. you can use another value depending on your table styles */
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td style="font-size:11px;">
    <div class="cell">Name <span>:</span></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font-size:11px;">
    <div class="cell">Date <span>:</span></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Also, you don't need `<br>` between your table rows (`<tr>`s).

Answer (score 2):

As the colon is for visual separation rather than having any meaning I would consider inserting it in a pseudo element rather than actually in the HTML.

This snippet puts the colon in just before the following td which ensures the colons are aligned.

```css
td:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: ':';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:11px;">Name </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr><br>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:11px;">Date</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish that is to put the colon at the beginning of
the 'text', instead of the end of the 'title'.

```css
/* Not relevant */

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td> : John Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <td> : Nov. 24, 2021</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Very long title</th>
    <td> : Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you need to omit it when the 'text' is empty, you can output the colon as a `td::before` using CSS.

```css
/* This is relevant */

td:not(:empty)::before {
  content: " : ";
}


/* Not relevant */

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>John Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <td>Nov. 24, 2021</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Very long title</th>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have updated your sample code put the `:` in second td

```html
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Full Name</td>
        <td>: Abc def</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>: 24-11-2021</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If its about a single word followed by a **:**, `text-align-last:justify;` can do the job

```css
td.adjust {
  text-align-last: justify;
  padding-inline-end:0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="adjust">Name :</td>
    <td>Name </td>
  </tr><br>
  <tr>
    <td class="adjust">Date :</td>
    <td>Today</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```